# Sharing live file upload folders with dev

Tags: files

I have a scenario where I would like to share the live file upload folders for a site with the dev environment. Both environments are on the same server so I've created a symbolic link in the dev environment pointing at each of the corresponding folders in the live environment. This works perfectly well over SFTP, I can click into one of these folders in dev and I see the contents of the folder on live.

However I'm unable to access files in these folders via HTTP requests. Is there something I'm missing? It seems like an obvious approach to the problem but maybe it's not that simple?

This is a pretty old site so we're stuck with 1.x (1.7.1 at present) else I would use the lovely new file upload location config vars to resolve the situation. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is more a question about servers, than about EECMS.

If you're using Apache, add this to the .htaccess file of your dev website:

```
Options FollowSymlinks
```

You can read more about this at the [documentation](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#Options) of Apache.